# Get a list of input

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, webforms

This is the html:

```
<input type="text" value="Google" name="Projects[0]" />
 <input type="text" value="Microsoft" name="Projects[1]" />
 <input type="text" value="Microsoft" name="Projects[2]" />
```

This also has an ASPX submit button.

```
<asp:Button ID="submitBtn" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
```

--- C# -----------

```
 protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        List<string> projectsInCSharp = new List<string>();
        projectsInCSharp.Add(Request["Projects[0]"]); //Google
        projectsInCSharp.Add(Request["Projects[1]"]); //Microsoft

    }
```

Is there a better way to do this and bind it in a list automatically. For instance in ASP.NET MVC you can do this. However I am using WebForms and I can't switch to MVC for just this.

I am using .NET 4.0, C#, ASPX.

Comment: do you know before hand how many html input text you need to create?

Comment: Its dynamic. I made it a list to handle any number of inputs. It should work for any number, right?

Comment: if it is a list then you will be able to get the count of it right?

Comment: Umm yes I should be able to get a count. That is what I am trying to do in c# :) : to put it in a list. Once it gets saved in a list automatically, my mission is completed. (In client/browser the html  is generated by Javascript dynamically.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code, you can use AddRange instead of calling Add multiple times:

```
        List<string> projectsInCSharp = new List<string>();
        projectsInCSharp.AddRange(Request.Params
            .Cast<string>()
            .Where(o => o.StartsWith("Projects["))
            .OrderBy(o => int.Parse(o.Remove(o.Length - 1, 1).Remove(0, 9)))
            .Select(o => Request.Params[o])
            );
```

Or you can put it in a constructor:

```
        List<string> projectsInCSharp = new List<string>(
            Request.Params
                .Cast<string>()
                .Where(o => o.StartsWith("Projects["))
                .OrderBy(o => int.Parse(o.Remove(o.Length - 1, 1).Remove(0, 9)))
                .Select(o => Request.Params[o])
            );
```

Comment: This looks pretty good. My only comment would be that it will use string ordering so it would sort them as `Projects[1]`,`Projects[10]`,`Projects[2]`... Other than that an excellent answer. :)

Comment: Thanks :) 
This is what I was looking for at this moment :) 
Great man .. Cool.

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris, you noticed the sorting issue very well :)

Comment: @Rajesh You're welcome, I fixed the sorting so it sorts the list according to the index `i` in `Projects[i]` instead of the alphabetical sorting. Of course, if you don't need this list sorted you can omit the `OrderBy` method.

Answer (score 5):

This is a hacky workaround, but what you could do is use the fact that a browser will comma delimit post fields which have the same `name` attribute.

i.e. By changing your aspx to:

```
<input type="text" value="Google" name="Project" />
<input type="text" value="Microsoft" name="Project" />
<input type="text" value="Oracle" name="Project" />
```

You can then do a one liner in your Code Behind:

```
List<string> projectsInCSharp = Request["Project"].Split(',').ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks nonnb for this answer however, I don't want to delimit using commas. I had issues before with the commas. 
This is great, is there a better solution. :)

Comment: I've upvoted Ivan G's answer - its a bit less hacky than mine :)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer as well because it is also helpful when you are using comma separated stuffs. :) Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that along with the input textboxes you also pass the count in a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="textBoxCount" value="10" /> //you will need to pass it
```

so given that we know the Count of TextBoxes

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   List<string> projectsInCSharp = new List<string>();
   int count = Convert.ToInt32(Request["textBoxCount"]);
   for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
   {
      if(Request["Projects[" +  i + "]"] != null)
      { 
        projectsInCSharp.Add(Request["Projects[" +  i + "]"]);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Hat :).